# Getting a div to shrink in JQuery accordion

Tags: html, jquery, css

I apologize upfront because I'm a bad coder in that I know very little, but just enough to pull what I need and make it work. To that end, I have a large graphic divided into six pieces. Using [JqueryTools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion-horizontal.html), I have it set up as an accordion to where when each piece is clicked, it opens to reveal another accordion list that expands to present the data needed. It's old and dirty (yes) but it has worked for what it needed to up to this point.

The trouble is, the information that needs to display inside each slice has changed to where we need more real estate to display the content. What I'd like to do (ideally) is either on hover or click is for the area where the image slice is, to shrink/go away so that the inner space takes it over. In other words, the "tab" triggers the inner section to open and expand to where the tab is no longer visible.

This is the current code:

```
$(#accordion").tabs("#accordion div", {
tabs: 'img.banner',
effect: 'horizontal',
initialIndex: 'null,
});
function openFirstPanel(){
$('.accordionside > dt:first-child').next().addClass('active').slideDown();
}
(function($) {
var allPanels = $('.accordioninside > dd').hide();
openFirstPanel();
$('.accordioninside > dt > a').click(function() {
$this = $(this).parent().next();
if($target.hasClas('active')){
$target.removeClass('active').slideUp();
}else{
AllPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
$target.addClass('active).slideDown();
}
return false;
});
```

I've tried a few things with no luck. I'm open to completely re-doing it in a different way. The main thing is that it is one graphic cut into six pieces that need to slide open to reveal internal content and ideally slide to take over the image/tab and gain that real estate.

I apologize for the inelegant code, but any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a runnable example? Use the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar. Also, looks like some single quotes are missing? (the end of `initialIndex` and the last `addClass`)